# How can I set a MYSQL date or datetime variable that will make this simple query work?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

How can I set a MYSQL date or datetime variable that will make this simple query work?

```
set @dateTo  :=cast('2016-09-30' as date);
SELECT 
    id, last_updated
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM transactions_history WHERE id = 81867533) h
WHERE
      DATE(last_updated) <= '2016-09-30'  --550 Rows
    --DATE(last_updated) <=  @date_To   --0 Rows
```

---

This query returns 550 rows, but when the last line is substituted for the second last line, 0 rows are returned.

Here's a few lines of the output ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WClod.png)):

```
+ -------- + ------------------- +
| id       | last_updated        |
+ -------- + ------------------- +
| 81867533 | 2016-09-14 22:25:42 |
| 81867533 | 2016-09-14 23:30:21 |
| 81867533 | 2016-09-15 00:39:45 |
| 81867533 | 2016-09-15 00:39:45 |
| 81867533 | 2016-09-15 01:02:03 |
| 81867533 | 2016-09-15 02:28:23 |
+ -------- + ------------------- +
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your attempt.  Instead of:

```
WHERE DATE(last_updated) <=  @date_To   --0 Rows
```

Remove the underscore:

```
WHERE DATE(last_updated) <=  @dateTo
```

The variable needs to match the definition.